# I suspect a wrong tag (typo) for jersy

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I suspect [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19701738/628006) has been wrongly tagged with [jersy](/questions/tagged/jersy) instead [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey).

Comment: should I delete this question because the duplicate?

Comment: No, and besides, you won't be able to, since the question has already acquired an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see such a tag, correct it then and there. The now-unused tag will get deleted automatically within 24 hours (usually).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I used the duplicate link recommendation to remove the tag and assign the new one.